# How do I make a JDO query using contains()?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I have a class with an enum as instance variable:

```
  public enum Races {
     Human, Elf, Orc, Troll
  }

  @PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
  public class Crafter {
     @PrimaryKey
     @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
     private Key key;
     @Persistent
     private Races race;
  }
```

I have been able to store and retrieve instances of that class, this is not the problem.

The problem comes when I want to query on, let's say, all the orcs and troll.

```
  Races[] races = new Races[] { Races.Orc, Races.Troll, };

  Query query = manager.newQuery(Crafter.class);
  query.setFilter(":raceParam.contains(race)");
  List<Crafter> crafters = (List<Crafter>) query.execute(Arrays.asList(races));
```

It doesn't work, I get:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: race: ca.forklabs.wowtradeskills.web.shared.Races is not a supported property type.
      at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:184)
      at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:149)
      at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterPredicate.<init>(Query.java:574)
      at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.addFilter(Query.java:260)
      at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery.addLeftPrimaryExpression(DatastoreQuery.java:1343)
            ...
```

How does one do IN queries using JDO with the Google App Engine?

Some references:

- http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2009/12/queries-with-and-in-filters.html
- http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/jdoql_methods.html

Answer (score 0):

**contains** in JDOQL is defined like in Java ... on a Collection (field). You have an array. JDOQL syntax follows Java syntax

Comment: I am not following you. I am passing a list to the execute() method as a parameter and calling the contains() on my parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ahh, yes. So maybe GAE version you're using doesn't support a Collection parameter; all I can comment on is validity of the JDOQL

Comment: mr datanucleus, I have the last version of GAE with datanucleus datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0 and this doesn't work! any thoughts? even on strings.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I have successfully been doing contains() in JDOQL (DataNucleus implementation) using the 'matches' method:

```
matches(String pattern)
```

> Returns whether string matches the passed expression. The pattern
> argument follows the rules of java.lang.String.matches method. Only
> the following regular expression patterns are required to be supported
> and are portable: global “(?i)” for case-insensitive matches; and “.”
> and “.*” for wild card matches. The pattern passed to matches must be
> a literal or parameter.

For example:

To add a filter clause that checks if the companyName attribute 'contains' the text stored in criteria in a case insensitive way:

```
query.setFilter("companyName.matches(\"(?i).*" + criteria + ".*\")");
```

Check out the methods section on this page:

https://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/query.html#jdoql_methods